# "so..... as" OR "as...... as"

Tags: phrase-usage

1. This test is **not as** difficult **as** that one.
2. This test is **not so** difficult **as** that one.
3. He was**n't** **so** quick a learner **as** his brother.
4. He was**n't as** quick a learner as his brother.

Are all these sentences correct? I am not sure if "Not so..as" and "not as...as" interchangeable. (exam point of view)

I search about this than come to know about rules:

1. "so...as/as....as" is used for negative sentences and "as...as" is used in affirmative sentences.

Can you please clarify if this rules are correct?

Comment: Both mean the same thing, at least in this context. I agree that "so ... as" is used for negative sentences, *"He is not so tall as she"* but "as ... as" can be used for either, *"He is (not) as tall as she"*.  The use of "so" is perhaps *slightly* more formal.

Comment: Using *so* feels a bit more high-toned to me, otherwise no difference.

Answer (score 2):

You should use *as...as*.

> This test is not **as** difficult **as** that one.
>   He wasn't **as** quick a learner **as** his brother.

If you want to use *so*, then:

> This test is not **so** difficult **compared to/with** that one.
>   He wasn't **so** quick a learner **compared to/with** his brother.